# How to fix ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and continuous targets to get F1_score

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, networkx

I'm trying to get F1 score but I keep on getting `ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and continuous targets`

Here's my code

```
# Prediction using Adamic Adar 
pred_adamic = list(nx.adamic_adar_index(PDZ1_G_train))
score_adamic, label_adamic = zip(*[(s, (u,v) in edge_subset) for (u,v,s) in pred_adamic])

# Compute the ROC AUC Score
fpr_adamic, tpr_adamic, _ = roc_curve(label_adamic, score_adamic)
auc_adamic = roc_auc_score(label_adamic, score_adamic)

fxxxx1 = f1_score(label_adamic, score_adamic)
```

here's the error log

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-147-5fc89281c63b> in <module>
----> 1 fxxxx1 = f1_score(label_adamic, score_adamic)

c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py in f1_score(y_true, y_pred, labels, pos_label, average, sample_weight, zero_division)
   1094     modified with ``zero_division``.
   1095     """
-> 1096     return fbeta_score(y_true, y_pred, 1, labels=labels,
   1097                        pos_label=pos_label, average=average,
   1098                        sample_weight=sample_weight,

c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py in fbeta_score(y_true, y_pred, beta, labels, pos_label, average, sample_weight, zero_division)
   1217     """
   1218 
-> 1219     _, _, f, _ = precision_recall_fscore_support(y_true, y_pred,
   1220                                                  beta=beta,
   1221                                                  labels=labels,

c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py in precision_recall_fscore_support(y_true, y_pred, beta, labels, pos_label, average, warn_for, sample_weight, zero_division)
   1481     if beta < 0:
   1482         raise ValueError("beta should be >=0 in the F-beta score")
-> 1483     labels = _check_set_wise_labels(y_true, y_pred, average, labels,
   1484                                     pos_label)
   1485 

c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py in _check_set_wise_labels(y_true, y_pred, average, labels, pos_label)
   1299                          str(average_options))
   1300 
-> 1301     y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
   1302     present_labels = unique_labels(y_true, y_pred)
   1303     if average == 'binary':

c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py in _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
     87 
     88     if len(y_type) > 1:
---> 89         raise ValueError("Classification metrics can't handle a mix of {0} "
     90                          "and {1} targets".format(type_true, type_pred))
     91 

ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and continuous targets
```

Here's the data :

[image]

Comment: What are your `label_adamic`, `score_adamic` values? It appears one of them is continuous and the other is binary.

Comment: Indeed, pls post a sample if the said variables.

Comment: `label_adamic` is a tuple of Boolean values and `score_adamic` is a tuple of float values @DhavalTaunk @desertnaut

Comment: Yupp, there is a value `0.9102392266268373` which is not a binary value. Binary values are usually 0 or 1. You should consider it converting into binary by some thresholding according to your case.  @Teetee

Comment: is this what you mean by binary converting : ` def DecimalToBinary(num):
        if (num >= 0.1):
            return 1 
        else: 
            return 0` 

I've tried this and i've got `f1_score = 0.0 ` @DhavalTaunk

Comment: This should not happen. Try once checking the datatype of both the tuples after thresholding.

Comment: how did you solve this problem